# MySql use 'LIKE' and 'IN' together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an example table `ExampleTable` (`Name` and `Code` are `VARCHAR`):

```
Name     Code
test1    2016/554
test2    2016/13554
test3    2015/9893
test4    2015/74584
```

and I have a working query in Visual Studio:

```
select *  from Example_Table where  code LIKE '%' + '2016' + '%'
```

but I want that user can define string which contains part of code. These parts are separated by '`,`'.

Example: string = `2016,745` and I want to get `test1,test2,test4`.

```
select *  from Example_Table where  code LIKE IN (string with elements)
```

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server?  Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from [ExampleTable] where code LIKE '%2016%' or code LIKE '%745%';
```

this will do the job, and get answer as test1,test2,test4

use OR operator.

Refference
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html

Comment: But iI do not know how many items in string will be. How I can do it dynamic?

Comment: count the strings, then use OR operators and concatenate to the sql command. then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

... WHERE code = '%str1%' OR code = '%str2%' OR code = '%str3'...